# Мобильная версия сайта или специальное приложение

Tags: android, bootstrap

Добрый день. Я делаю клиентскую часть клиент-серверной системы. В качестве клиента мобильное приложение. По тз к серверной части полагается что то вроде панели управления для оператора. Сейчас в обсуждении наметилось два пути:

1. Сделать обычное приложение, которое запросами к серверу получает\передает всю нужную инфу.
2. Сверстать пару страниц, с использованием bootstrap и показывать их через WebView.

Я более тяготею к первому варианту, так как из приложения нужно будет совершать звонки. Какой вариант вы бы выбрали и почему?

Comment: В конечном итоге было решено делать нативное приложение. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из собственного опыта, считаю нативное приложение более подходящим вариантом. 
Плюсы натива - более высокая скорость обработки команд, гибкость построения запросов и обработки ответов,несколько большая, на мой взгляд, защищенность.
Минусы - необходимость правки отдельной программы в случае изменений в серверной части и, соответственно, обновления ПО у пользователей.
Однако, этот минус имеет большую вероятность возникновения и при использовании гибридной системы (WEB + JavascriptInterface)

Answer (score 1):

Это сильно зависит от функционала. Вообще абстрактного "сферического коня в вакууме" лучше писать нативно. С другой стороны, если функционал небогатый - можно использовать и WebView. Кроме того, есть такие полезные штуки, как cordova, которые позволяют использовать нативные функции дивайсов на JS.
также есть вариант комбинировать это все. Например, все, кроме звонков написать через WebView, и добавить к нему [JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html), который позволит вызывать любые , описанные вами методы из webView в нативный код.